# Sounds like a story, romantic - What am I?

Tags: riddle

Your heart pumps, asking why,
"I am here to make you cry.
It's hard to say goodbye
but leave me so you could fly."

your mind said love, but your body said hate
happiness is together and you gain weight.
Like when we met on our first date.
Nothing but fruit you have ate.

Sounds like a story, romantic,
nothing around me but tragic.
Here I will show you a magic,
I'll vanish and you will panic!

> I might be the reason you fall in love,
>  but love is nothing I planned to speak of.
>  I am massive and I can be related,
>  Two great mind in history have debated.

Comment: The spoilertagged hint makes me think of either light or gravity, but I can't make either fit the rest of the riddle...

Comment: I was thinking it could be water, but then how does water eat gruit?

Comment: @JoeZ. I don't think it needs to be anything that can eat fruit, since it says "fruit *you* have ate".

Comment: @ I see the answer already =D, it just needs to be spell out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rand al'thor mentioned, the answer is **gravity**.

> Your heart pumps, asking why

Your heart has to work against gravity to pump blood to your head.

> "I am here to make you cry.
>   It's hard to say goodbye,
>   But leave me so you could fly."

Without gravity pulling you down to the earth, you could fly.

> Your mind said love, but your body said hate

I'm not sure how this line applies.

> happiness is together and you gain weight.

Gravity causes things with mass to have weight as well.

> Like when we met on our first date.

I'm not sure how this line applies.

> Nothing but fruit you have ate.

Sir Isaac Newton discovered gravity while watching an apple fall.

> Sounds like a story, romantic,
>   nothing around me but tragic.

The gravity of a situation, for example.

> Here I will show you a magic,
>   I'll vanish and you will panic!

If gravity were to vanish, nothing could hold itself together anymore, and you would die.

> I might be the reason you fall in love,
>   But love is nothing I planned to speak of.

Gravity is the reason you ever fall at all. Love is irrelevant there, which is what the second line is for.

> I am massive and I can be related,

Gravity affects masses, and is a component of general relativity.

> Two great minds in history have debated.

Copernicus and Galileo, I assume?

Comment: Nice!  You got most of them correct, i'll accept your answer.  However try to figure out: "i'm here to make you cry", "I am massive and I can be related" and "Two great minds in history have debated".

Comment: My relativity answer is wrong?

Comment: misread, your line on relativity is correct

Comment: Well done! I couldn't make all those lines fit, but the third line of the hint put me onto this solution.